# AP_SOUTH_1 region is not present in Regions enum

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am trying a small dynamoDB example. Because regions for my dynamoDB tables is Mumbai(ap-south-1), I am setting client as following:

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1));
this.dynamoDb = new DynamoDB(client);
```

Unfortunately, AP_SOUTH_1 is not getting resolved.

My pom file looks like below:

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: As @helloV says, your DynamoDB library is 2.5 years old and I can't even find your core library version.  As AWS adds features - services, regions, etc. - you need to update the libraries to keep up.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible your SDK is not the latest and has no enum for `AP_SOUTH_1`. Either get the latest SDK or use:

```
Region.getRegion("ap-south-1")
```

From: [AWS Region Selection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-region-selection.html)

> If the region you are attempting to use isn't in the Regions enum, **you
>   can set the region using a string** that represents the name of the
>   region.

Comment: You are right about me using old version of SDK. But even the workout you specified won't work with old version as internally Enum is checked with equality.